# Como capturar el valor de un select o input text para enviarlo por ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Buenos días estoy intentando capturar el valor de un `select` que esta fuera de un formulario para enviarlo a una BD, con un ejemplo que me dieron en este sitio logre enviar 3 parámetros pero el del `select` siempre envía el primer item y no el que selecciono entonces intente enviar lo que selecciono a un `input` text pero me lo envía vació, este es el código con el que capturo lo del `select` en un `input`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function selecOp()
        {
        var op=document.getElementById("no_conformidad");
        var tt=document.getElementById("text");
        if (op.selectedIndex==0)tt.value="";
        if (op.selectedIndex==1)tt.value="MESA-1";
        if (op.selectedIndex==2)tt.value="MESA-2";
        if (op.selectedIndex==3)tt.value="MESA-3";
        if (op.selectedIndex==4)tt.value="MESA-4";
        if (op.selectedIndex==5)tt.value="MESA-5";
        if (op.selectedIndex==6)tt.value="MESA-6";
        }
          var mesa=document.getElementById("text");
        </script>
        <select name="no_conformidad" id="no_conformidad" onchange="selecOp()">
        <option>Selecciona una mesa</option>
        <option>MESA-1</option>
        <option>MESA-2</option>
        <option>MESA-3</option>
        <option>MESA-4</option>
        <option>MESA-5</option>
        <option>MESA-6</option></select>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" size="4">
```

y con este lo envio por ajax

```
   <script>
  <script>
     $(document).on('ready',function(){
        //var mesa=document.getElementById("text").value;
            mesa = document.getElementById("text").value//obtener valor del 
      input

            var item = $('#it1').val();
           var precio = $('#it2').val();
       $('#boton1').click(function(){
         var url = "enviar.php";
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data:{mesa:mesa,item:item,precio:precio},
            success: function(data)
            {
            //  $('#resp').html(data);
            }
          });
          alert(mesa);
            return false;
       });
     });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener un valor de un `select` puedes usar `event.target.value` y pasarlo como parámetro en la función `change()` o obtener su valor usando `document.getElementById("no_conformidad").value` espero te ayude saludos.

> NOTA: Para obtener los valores de un select tienes que agregar `value="valor del select"` lo que esta dentro del `html` `<option value="MESA-1">`**--->MESA-1**`</option>` es lo que ve el usuario.

```js
var valorEnvio = ""

function selecOp(valor){
  document.getElementById("valorDeSelect").value = valor//declararle el valor del select al input
}

function obtenerValor(){
  valor = document.getElementById("valorDeSelect").value//obtener valor del input
  valorEnvio = valor //declarar valor a la variable a usar en el ajax
  console.log(valorEnvio)
  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="no_conformidad" id="no_conformidad" onchange="selecOp(event.target.value)">
        <option value="Selecciona una mesa">Selecciona una mesa</option>
        <option value="MESA-1">MESA-1</option>
        <option value="MESA-2">MESA-2</option>
        <option value="MESA-3">MESA-3</option>
        <option value="MESA-4">MESA-4</option>
        <option value="MESA-5">MESA-5</option>
        <option value="MESA-6">MESA-6</option></select>
        <input id="valorDeSelect" type="text" name="" value="">
        
        <br>
        
        <button onclick="obtenerValor()" type="button" name="button">Obtener valor del Input</button>
```

**Solución al problema de obtener datos**

Tienes que cambiar la obtención de los datos y ponerlo dentro del evento `click`
al estar afuera no va a encontrar los datos.

```
<script>
 <script>
 $(document).on('ready',function(){
    //var mesa=document.getElementById("text").value;

   $('#boton1').click(function(){
    mesa = document.getElementById("text").value//obtener valor del input


       var item = $('#it1').val();
       var precio = $('#it2').val();
     var url = "enviar.php";
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data:{mesa:mesa,item:item,precio:precio},
        success: function(data)
        {
        //  $('#resp').html(data);
        }
      });
      alert(mesa);
        return false;
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: hola gracias por responder cuando le pongo esta intruccion  valor = document.getElementById("no_conformidad").value  me envia siempre el primero que es "Selecciona una mesa"

Comment: revisa la nota que puse y agrégale el `value="valor a enviar"` a ver si así funciona

Comment: Disculpa no comprendo muy bien tu nota pero lo voy a explicar de otra forma al seleccionar del un item del select el me lo envia a un input text ahora como hago para recoger ese valor del input text en una variable para poder enviarlo por ajax?

Comment: Ya cambie el ejemplo espero sea lo que buscas agregue una variable `valorEnvio` que se llena con el valor que tiene el `input` y lo único que tienes que hacer es usarla como parámetro en el **ajax**

Comment: mira modifique el codigo de ajax con lo que me dices miralo a ver si hago algo mal porque me sigue enviando vacio y el input en la pagina se muestra con valor.

Comment: intenta con quitarle la function `change` `selecOp()` y prueba y agrega el js siempre al final de todo el html

Comment: si le quito esa funcion ya no me envia al input, pero ya no es problema lo del select lo que requiero es recoger el valor que se ve en el input

Comment: ya te acomode la respuesta revisala el error esta en cuando preguntas por el valor del `input` tiene que ser dentro de la ejecución del click

Comment: woow si gracias era eso aunque no comprendo porque con las otras dos lo hacia por fuera del click pero bueno, esa era la respuesta muy agradecido amigo.

Comment: dale como respuesta correcta para ayudar a los demas programadores que tengan el mismo problema saludos que bueno ayudarte.